# Applying a handlebar helper to another handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am trying to use Handlebars to return all distinct values in a column.
The following Handlebars template returns all the values in the column "hostname" of my dataframe.

```
{{#each data}} {{"hostname.keyword"}} {{/each}}
```

This contains duplicate values and so I defined a helper to remove those duplicates.

```
handlebars.registerHelper("unique", (context) =>
  [...new Set(context)]);
```

I'm not able to figure out how to pass the result returned by the Handlebars `#each` block as an argument to the helper. For instance,

```
<div>{{unique ({{#each data}} {{"hostname.keyword"}} {{/each}})}}</div>
```

results in the following error:

```
    Parse error on line 2:
.../h5><div>{{unique ({{#each data}} {{"ho
----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'OPEN_BLOCK'
```

The following does not produce any error, but it returns nothing:

```
<div>{{unique data "hostname.keyword"}}</div>
```

Is it possible to do this? And if so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to take the output of a block helper - like `#each` - and process it through an inline helper, like `unique`. What you would have to do instead is to have your custom helper do both the mapping of the objects to their value at the specified key (`hostname.keyword`) and then *also* filter the result set so as to have only unique values. Once you have the mapped and filtered result, you would pass that to the `#each` block helper.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile('<div>{{#each (unique data "hostname.keyword")}}{{this}}{{/each}}</div>');

Handlebars.registerHelper("unique", (context, key) => {
  return [...new Set(context.map(item => item[key]))];
});

const data = [
  {
    "hostname.keyword": "a"
  },
  {
    "hostname.keyword": "b"
  },
  {
    "hostname.keyword": "a"
  }
];

const output = template({ data });

document.body.innerHTML = output;
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```